# How to store subset of a multiindex dataframe in a new dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, select, dataframe, multi-index

I have a multiindex dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'ind1': list('aaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbb'),
                   'ind2': list('cccdddeeecccdddeee'),
                   'ind3': list(range(3))*6,
                   'val1': list(range(100, 118)),
                   'val2': list(range(70, 88))})

df_mult = df.set_index(['ind1', 'ind2', 'ind3'])

                val1  val2
ind1 ind2 ind3            
a    c    0      100    70
          1      101    71
          2      102    72
     d    0      103    73
          1      104    74
          2      105    75
     e    0      106    76
          1      107    77
          2      108    78
b    c    0      109    79
          1      110    80
          2      111    81
     d    0      112    82
          1      113    83
          2      114    84
     e    0      115    85
          1      116    86
          2      117    87
```

I can now select a subset of it using `.loc` like this

```
df_subs = df_mult.loc['a', ['c', 'd'], :]
```

which gives the expected

```
                val1  val2
ind1 ind2 ind3            
a    c    0      100    70
          1      101    71
          2      102    72
     d    0      103    73
          1      104    74
          2      105    75
```

If I now want to select again a subset of `df_subs`, e.g.

```
df_subs.loc['a', 'c', :]
```

works and gives

```
      val1  val2
ind3            
0      100    70
1      101    71
2      102    72
```

however

```
df_subs.loc[:, 'c', :]
```

fails and gives an error

> KeyError: 'the label [c] is not in the [columns]'

Why does this fail?

**EDIT**

Originally, I had two question in this post. I splitted it into two, the second question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46624457/why-do-i-see-all-original-index-elements-in-a-sliced-dataframe).

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html why not using `slice` or `IndexSlice`

Comment: @Wen: Sure, there might be better options but I would still like to understand why the above attempts fail. If the attempts are wrong altogether, then it would be great to see the correct way of doing it i.e. working alternatives.

Comment: @JohnE: Ok, that's already good to know. I still need to figure out when exactly I would have to use an `IndexSlice`. But seems it does not change anything for question 1: `df_mult.loc[pd.IndexSlice['a', ['c', 'd'], :], :].index` still shows me `a` and `b` in level 0; any idea why?

Comment: This is not an answer and I'm not an expert on this but my personal experience is that using loc with a multiindex can be a matter of trial and error.  Quoting from the docs linked to by @wen:  "Syntactically integrating MultiIndex in advanced indexing with .loc is a bit challenging, but we’ve made every effort to do so."  Interpret that as you will.  ;-)

Comment: @JohnE: Ok, then I will from now on always use `IndexSlice` when working with multiindex dataframes :).

Comment: @Cleb  I don't know the answer to question #1 and you probably have to look at pandas internal code to figure it out.  But I don't see that it's a problem in any way, just arguable a slightly wasteful use of memory.  If it really bothers you, of course you could just reset_index and then (again) set index, but I really don't think it's a meaningful issue.

Comment: @JohnE: It could become an issue if I want to use the elements of the index for something else. Then `df_subs.index.levels[0]` gives me `Index([u'a', u'b'], dtype='object', name=u'ind1')`, however, `df_subs.index.get_level_values('ind1').unique()` gives me `Index([u'a'], dtype='object', name=u'ind1')` which looks inconsistent to me.

Comment: yeah, fair point!  altho I'm a little unsure of the practical importance 99.9% of the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `IndexSlice`:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df_subs.loc[idx[:, 'c',:],:]
Out[159]: 
                val1  val2
ind1 ind2 ind3            
a    c    0      100    70
          1      101    71
          2      102    72
```

Or you need to specific slice on row or column

```
df_subs.loc(axis=0)[:, 'c', :]
Out[196]: 
                val1  val2
ind1 ind2 ind3            
a    c    0      100    70
          1      101    71
          2      102    72
```

The reason why `.loc[:, 'c', :]` can not work :

***You should specify all axes in the .loc specifier, meaning the indexer for the index and for the columns. There are some ambiguous cases where the passed indexer could be mis-interpreted as indexing both axes, rather than into say the MuliIndex for the rows.***

[Link1](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers)

[Link2](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13597)

Comment: Ok, great to know a working alternative (upvoted). However, do you know why the version with `.loc` is not working? Also `df_subs.loc[idx[:, 'c',:],:].index` still has `a` and `b` in level 0; any idea why?

Comment: @Cleb it is a discuss in git. you can check the two link I provided ~ :-) to be more safe , you can just using slice or IndexSlice:)

Comment: Interesting read, thanks. I also edited my question regarding question 1; any comments about this? (By now I am not sure anymore whether this is actually related so I should have splitted it into two questions I think).

Comment: @Cleb I am not very sure about your q1, Just guess it , should be something like category or factor , even you slice them , they still showing the original level

Comment: Ok. I will remove this part and open a new question for it. Then I can accept your answer here already. Give me a few minutes... :)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, using `.loc` may persist the indices in its original form until they are reset. Using `.copy()` to avoid any views of original dataframe still persists multindex value.

```
df_subs = df_mult.loc['a', ['c', 'd'], :].copy()

print(df_subs.index)
# MultiIndex(levels=[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], [0, 1, 2]],
#            labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]],
#            names=['ind1', 'ind2', 'ind3'])
```

Additionally, filtering by values still retains multindex values:

```
df_subs = df_mult[df_mult['val1'] <= 105]

print(df_subs)
#                 val1  val2
# ind1 ind2 ind3            
# a    c    0      100    70
#           1      101    71
#           2      102    72
#      d    0      103    73
#           1      104    74
#           2      105    75

print(df_subs.index)
# MultiIndex(levels=[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], [0, 1, 2]],
#            labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]],
#            names=['ind1', 'ind2', 'ind3'])
```

Therefore, consider manually resetting index, following your original assignment

```
df_subs = df_mult.loc['a', ['c', 'd'], :].reset_index()

df_subs = df_subs.set_index(['ind1', 'ind2', 'ind3'])

print(df_subs.index)
# MultiIndex(levels=[['a'], ['c', 'd'], [0, 1, 2]],
#            labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]],
#            names=['ind1', 'ind2', 'ind3'])
```

Finally, for last `.loc` assignment (#2), provide at least the first index as may be required:

```
df_subs2 = df_subs.loc['a', 'c', :]
#       val1  val2
# ind3            
# 0      100    70
# 1      101    71
# 2      102    72
```